# How do I put a string in a list at every nth index?

Tags: python, list, python-3.x, join

I'm working on a function that gets the suit and value as a string in a list from another function:

```
def getCard(n):
    deckListSuit = []
    grabSuit = getSuit(n)
    n = (n-1) % 13 + 1
    if n == 1:
        deckListSuit.append("Ace")
        return deckListSuit + grabSuit
    if 2 <= n <= 10:
        deckListSuit.append(str(n))
        return deckListSuit + grabSuit
    if n == 11:
        deckListSuit.append("Jack")
        return deckListSuit + grabSuit
    if n == 12:
        deckListSuit.append("Queen")
        return deckListSuit + grabSuit
    if n == 13:
        deckListSuit.append("King")
        return deckListSuit + grabSuit
```

With the new function it is to take the information from the above function and return it in a list with a certain structure "VALUE of SUIT".

So say if you had "3", "Spades" it would return "3 of Spades" instead.

This is my code so far on the new function.

```
def getHand(myList):
    hand = []
    for n in myList:
        hand += getCard(n)
    return [(" of ".join(hand[:2]))] + [(" of ".join(hand[2:4]))] + [(" of ".join(hand[4:6]))] + [(" of ".join(hand[6:8]))] + [(" of ".join(hand[8:10]))]
```

My question is, is how do I insert "of" between the value and suit without having to do .join a million times?

Comment: Please, fix your indentation

Comment: @IronFist fixed

Comment: You still didn't fix the first part

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it in your `for` loop

```
for n in myList:
    hand += [" of ".join(getCard(n))]

return hand
```

You can also do it in `getCard` and return `'3 of Spades'`

---

BTW: you could keep it as tuples on list

```
hand = [ ("3", "Spades"), ("Queen", "Spades"), ... ]
```

then you can use `for` loop instead of slices `[:2]`, `[2:4]`

```
new_list = []
for card in hand: 
    # in `card` you have ("3", "Spades")
    new_list.append(' of '.join(card))

return new_list
```

Comment: What if I need more then one card? putting it in the loop only gives back one card even if I have 4 integers in the list.

Comment: no, it gives you 4 cards because you don't leave `for` loop after first card

Comment: You could shorten your second example to: `new_list = [' of '.join(card) for card in hand]`

Comment: @leaf yes I know but longer version should be more readable for beginners like OP.

Comment: @furas I don't see anywhere where the OP says he's a beginner, Are you pulling my leg ;)

Comment: @leaf see his code. I would change so many things in his code that he has to be beginner :)

Answer (score 0):

If you use a list of tuple you can do with format and list comprehension

```
test_hand = [("3","space"),("4","old")]
return ["{} of {}".format(i,z) for i,z in (test_hand)]
```

output:

```
 ['3 of space', '4 of old']
```